# How to modify json payload request and add new json parameter with Charles proxy

Tags: json, charles-proxy, web-api-testing

Could anyone advise if there is any way to modify the existing json payload request while adding another parameter to the existing request. I have tried using breakpoints but having trouble due to request timeout occurs.

for example the existing payload

```
{
    "Type": "Games",
    "System": "Playstation"
}
```

and I would like to modify while adding a new parameter

```
{
    "Type": "Games",
    "System": "Playstation",
    "Name": "Call of duty"
}
```

Would it be possible to use rewrite or any available workarounds with Charles?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this fairly easily with the 'Rewrite' tool/feature.

[This article](https://charlesdocsy.com/2020/05/15/rewrite-modify-parts-of-response) will give you a more detail about modifying elements of Requests/Response bodies if you are interested

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It might not a direct question, but you can achieve it with simple JS code from [Scripting Tool](https://docs.proxyman.io/scripting/snippet-code#json-body)

[image]

JS Code:

```js
function onResponse(context, url, request, response) {

  // Update status Code
  response.statusCode = 500;

  // Done
  return response;
}
```

Disclaimer: I'm a creator of Proxyman.